# How can I store an image in MySQL database using Razor Pages?

Tags: mysql, image, input, razor, razor-pages

I am learning web development and working on Razor Pages. For my last assignment I was asked to make a website. In my website people can upload images and others see these images. The problem is I dont know how to store those photos. My tutor said if I save them in my sql table as binary values, that makes it very slow. I have to find another way. Can I convert image inputs to Url and store them as "text" ? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file to the file system (`wwwroot/images`, for example) and the file name of the image in the database. Then construct the value for the `src` attribute from the saved filename:

```
<img src="/images/@Model.ImageFileName" alt="..." />
```

> My tutor said if I save them in my sql table as binary values, that
> makes it very slow.

I can't speak with any authority on MySQL, but you should test to see if there is actually a performance penalty, and if so, whether it's significant.

Comment: I put the path of the folder which I save the image to my database. The problem its like :     
   var path = @"C:\\Users\\mycomputer\\Desktop\\images\\";
but if I send this solution to someone else, then they cannot see the proper path. Can i change the first part of this path and it will be the same all the computers?

Comment: Don't save the path. It is of no use to you. Save the file name only and use it to construct the URL for the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

Store the Uploaded files in the File System and insert the path of the saved file in the DB.

This will help you to maintain the DB performance.

Thanks